# How to share content from our site to google plus

Tags: html

How to share content from our site to google plus

I tried it like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode('http://example.com');?>&via=example', 'Share on Google Plus', 'width=600,height=400,left=450').focus();" >
```

Here I can not share content from my site. How it is possible with this?
I want to share content (example: hello) to goggle plus with sharing capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. You can paste a content from your app which you have to set as a default data.. https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#button_attr_calltoactionurl

Nothing much to do here..

Just  create a google plus app on the developers section. 
Then Paste the below portions

```
<button
  class="g-interactivepost"
 data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
  data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
  data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
  Tell your friends
</button>
```

Then change the data- client id.. Now it will work as per your expectation. Enjoy  :)

Answer (score 0):

Its been some time since the Google has brought its share button. You can find this, on their developer's page. [[Here]](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=gplusdevelopers&utm_campaign=shareplugin)

Paste the generated code on your web page, then link of the page will be automatically received by the API.

Comment: Can I pass a content to share with the link?

Comment: No, this flexibility is give to the user. When (s)he clicks the share button, (s)he will type the content, they want when sharing the page.