# Integrating Facebook,twitter,google plus into another app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter, integration

Integrating facebook,twitter and google plus into another web app, so that the posts in that app are posted write away as status in facebook,tweets in twitter and status in google plus.I am developing this using ruby on rails.I searched a lot about this but didn't find anything which would work for me.Can post some links or ideas which would be helpful for this.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2846283) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use Koala ( https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki ) to interface with Facebook. It's by far the best maintained fb library out there.

Otherwise, you should learn one thing or two about OAuth2:

- https://github.com/intridea/oauth2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
- https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Use https://github.com/sferik/twitter to interact with twitter.

For google, I've found that implementing the XML chat manually is easier than using any existing API wrapper. To convert XML responses into data, you an use a combination of the `Response#parsed` method of oauth2 gem and `Array.wrap` of ActiveSupport (there is no way for an XML parser to tell a single node to a possibly repeated node (so an array) that appears just once, avery big drawback of XML in my point of view)

Or you can directly ask google for JSON, so you already have the data correctly structured.

And, as @brendan-benson very correctly says, do only API calls in background workers, never in your normal request/responses cycle.

Answer (score 3):

For Facebook I must suggest you to use Koala Gem...

For Twitter
**Twitter**
https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons
 A twitter button can be easily generated here and placed on your web site..Its working great. You can even customize everything in twitter.. Its so user friendly.

For Google plus
**Google Plus**
I am just working on Google plus..Facing some difficulties as its having so many restrictions.
Still I would Like to Share a link you can follow that..

[How to share content from our site to google plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832670/how-to-share-content-from-our-site-to-google-plus/15879167#15879167)

I hope it will work fine...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of gems available to access these APIs:

- [Twitter API Wrapper](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/)
- [Facebook API Wrapper](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker)
- [Google Plus API Wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/)

Since APIs are flaky, it's best to use a queueing system like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) to queue the calls in Post#after_create, and then have a resque worker execute the call asynchronously.