# Gem to post message on google plus?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-plus

Is there any gem to post message on google plus from our rails application ?. I want to post a meesage on my google plus page whenever i logged in my application using google plus credentials. Please suggest me the gem name to do this. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have a app in goole plus. On behalf of my application users, my app should post messages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [**gem 'google_plus'**`](https://github.com/seejohnrun/google_plus)

As Google plus having so many restrictions. Still I would Like to Share a link you can follow that..

[How to share content from our site to google plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832670/how-to-share-content-from-our-site-to-google-plus/15879167#15879167)

**For more reference:**

- https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
- https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#button_attr_calltoactionurl

I hope it will work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a Ruby client library provided by Google which allows you consume their Google+ API

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/plus/v1

**UPDATE**
The URL above points to Ruby client library. The API you're looking for is `moments.insert`
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert

Comment: It that document there is no option to post a message.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [official Google API Client gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client). However the Google+ API does not allow standard automated posting to a profile. The recommended approach to share posts is the [share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) or the [interactive share API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive).

The automated posting that Google+ does support are:

- [App activities/moments](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/) are a way to make actions within your app visible to other users of your app. They do not appear in the Google+ posts stream.
- [Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert) can be used with Google Apps accounts to create posts that are limited to users within the company.
- [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) can be used to post to a page (not a profile) but is limited to approved partners.